# WordPress Audio Player

Tags: audio

I have a record pool website. I have various PLAY and PAUSE buttons for the file demos.

I need to make my progress bar activate whenever I click on the PLAY button that you can see in the attached image below.

I'm using this WordPress audio shortcode but is not activating when I click on the PLAY button.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[audio mp3='". $id . '" data-audio="' . $url . '" data-swf="' . $plugin_url . '/assets/js/jquery.jplayer/Jplayer.swf' ."']"); ?>
```

**In this attached picture I circled the PLAY buttons I have. What I need to do is when I click any of those play buttons I need the player to also activate so I can be able to scroll/skip through the playing track.**

[image]

I hope you guys understand my issue.

Comment: Have you checked your browsers dev console for error messages?

Comment: Not getting any error messages for that.